# Navigation Breaking Links By Word [Weebly]

Tags: html, css, weebly

I'm very new to website creation. I've been using Weebly and I have a navigation bar that I'd like to change up a bit. I got in contact with the support team as I was unable to do what I wanted to do - they said I would need (myself or someone else) to edit the HTML and CSS to get my desired output.

[Current Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Walhn.png)

This is my navigation bar - I'm looking to break each of the links into multi-line (if that makes sense). So where it says: "Management Consulting" - I want Management to be on top, and Consulting to be under that. Same goes for "Economic Development," "Strategic Communications," and "About Us." So navigation links with more than 1 word, I want to break by word.

I went to the Weebly navigation folder for the code: [Weebly Navigation Code Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c71Kp.png)

Here is the file `item.tpl`

```
<li {{#id}}id="{{id}}"{{/id}} class="wsite-menu-item-wrap">
    <a
        {{^nonclickable}}
            {{^nav_menu}}
                href="{{url}}"
            {{/nav_menu}}
        {{/nonclickable}}
        {{#target}}
            target="{{target}}"
        {{/target}}
        {{#membership_required}}
            data-membership-required="{{.}}"
        {{/membership_required}}
        class="wsite-menu-item"
        >
        {{{title_html}}}
    </a>
    {{#has_children}}{{> navigation/flyout/list}}{{/has_children}}
</li>
```

`list.tpl`

```
<ul class="wsite-menu-default">
    {{#links}}
        {{> navigation/item}}
    {{/links}}
</ul>
```

From my understanding (or lack there of), the "Flyout" is the mobile tab thing. So this shouldn't need an edit!

Is this doable? I appreciate it!

Comment: You can fix the width of each `li` so that the text goes to next line when there is an `overflow`.

Comment: Or just add a <br> in between the words

Comment: @Nivedita I thought of that, but wouldnt I have to "pick the right width"? How do I set the width of each <li> element?

Comment: @sn3ll I tried to do that, but the problem is Weebly was autoadjusting it back for me if I added a tag in the header

Comment: Maybe an escaped new line character "\n"??